# nodejs combime with typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I try to use typescript with nodejs. 
I don't understand why it show me error. Please help me fix it.
Here is my code (assum that I Import all module needed)
This is my `index.ts` file:

```
import routes from "./routes/routes";
let app = express();
app.use(routes);
```

This is my `routes/routes.ts`:

```
import * as homeRoute from "../apps/home/home.route";
    let app = express();
    export default function routes() {
        app.use("./home", homeRoute); // It show error in path: "./home"
        return app;
    }
```

This is my `home.route.ts`

```
  let router = express.Router();
    router.get("/", HomeController.hello); // it show error that property "hello" not exist
    // }
    module.exports = "homeRoute";
```

This is my `home.controller.ts`:

```
exports.hello = function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("Hello word");
}
```

Comment: How are importing `HomeController`?

Comment: Well, I just 
` import * as HomeController from ./home.controller.ts `
 in file home.route.ts

Comment: It's just what Klugjo says, you are using `exports.x = x` instead of `export const x`. That causes a compilation error since TypeScript does not recognize that in .ts files.

Answer (score 1):

In your `home.controller.ts` use an export statement instead:

```
export const hello = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("Hello word");
}
```

Then in your `home.route.ts` you have two ways of importing your controller method:

```
import * as HomeController from '../path/to/home.controller';

let router = express.Router();
router.get("/", HomeController.hello);
```

or

```
import {hello} from '../path/to/home.controller';

let router = express.Router();
router.get("/", hello);
```

Comment: This is correct, TypeScript doesn't consider assigning to properties on the `exports` object to be exports in `.ts` files.